# Phusion Passenger not reading .zshrc environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, zshrc

I am using Phusion Passenger 5.1.8 and have set the following in my `.zshrc`

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE='secure_key_base'
export DATABASE_NAME='db_production'
export DATABASE_PASSWORD='secure_db_pass'
```

I then did `source ~/.zshrc` and restart nginx with `sudo service nginx restart`. However, my application is complaining that it cannot find the SECRET_KEY_BASE and fails to start up. If I manually put these in `config/secrets.yml` then everything works well.

My `config/secrets.yml` has the following:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

and my `config/database.yml` file has:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Can someone please explain how I'd go about using zsh environment variables with Phusion Passenger?

Thanks!

Comment: Shutdown the nginx service and run `sudo nginx` from terminal and see if then it works

Comment: Nope that doesn't work :( makes no difference.

Comment: Try without sudo

Comment: Passenger needs to run with the sudo command, I'm quite sure. Check the docs: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/zesty/

Comment: I know a possible solution it just that I wanted to confirm few things before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that you are using your environment variable in .zshrc and you run nginx from systemd. Both have no connection to each other.

What you need is that your nginx should have these variable, which is run through a Systemd service. You need to use what is called a Drop-in

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d

cat > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/90-nginx-myapp.conf <<EOF
[Service]
Environment=SECRET_KEY_BASE=XYZ
Environment=SECRET_KEY_BASE2=XYZ2
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/myapp/environment
EOF
```

You can either use `Environment=` to declare a variable. Or you can use a file with environment variables.

Once you have added the drop-in, you need to reload systemd

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─90-nginx-myapp.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

And then use `systemctl restart nginx`

Now nginx should get the variables you want it to have.

**Edit-1**

If you need to use variables in both NGINX and your shell. The create a file with variables like beow

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=XYZ
SECRET_KEY_BASE2=XYZ2
```

In your drop-in use the `EnvironmentFile=` and in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` add the below lines

```
# set -a will make sure that X=Y is equivalent to export X=Y
set -a
source /etc/myapp/environment
# disable auto export of variable
set +a
```

Comment: I love you. Thanks so much

Comment: Interesting...this method seems to prevent commands like `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` from working. Obviously, because the env vars are being stored in an Nginx config. Is there some way you know to allow these variables to be stored both in Nginx and in environment variables that the rails command can access?